# Why Air bubble are always sphere in shape?

Tags: geometry, surface-tension, bubbles

Everyone of us had noticed air bubbles once in his life. They are Sphere in shape.
But I want to know why the are sphere in shape, instead of any other shape.

Comment: Think about : largest volume for the enclosing material... also pressure is equal in all directions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why sphere minimizes surface area for a given volume?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221210/)

Comment: why does volume matter? Soap bubbles aren't filled with soap.

Comment: @JEB did the OP mention soap?

Comment: @JEB  bubbles are not filled with vacuum, so volume and pressure matters

Comment: @JEB was that comment intended for me?

Comment: The "small" bubbles are spherical.  Larger bubbles rising through a water column are definitely NOT spherical.

Comment: @AaronStevensno I guess there is no soap. My bad, but soap bubbles are spherical and volume isn't the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are forced into a spherical shape by the pressure of water all around them, which is roughly equal on all sides, so the compressed air inside the bubble is forced into a shape which gives maximum volume for least surface area. However, bubbles are not always spherical, especially if they are very large bubbles. If you watch a wildlife programme on TV about marine or fresh water animals, you will see that the larger bubbles are often deformed by turbulence, and all bubbles gradually increase in size as they rise to the surface for the obvious reason that the nearer the surface the less the pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Surface tension.  Ps they can be deformed a bit by drag forces when rising up through a liquid.

Comment: I think you should ellaborate this answer a little more